# The following LateError was thrown building MyApp(dirty): LateInitializationError: Field 'token' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Exception caught by widgets library The following LateError was thrown building MyApp(dirty): LateInitializationError: Field 'token' has not been initialized.

[image]

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? It literally says what's wrong: `'token' has not been initialized.`

Comment: @IvoBeckers is right. You declared `late String? token` but never initialized token. It's called `null-safety` in Dart. Read about it here -> https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: @mutantkeyboard the issue here is not about null-safety actually, but about accessing a `late` property that hasn't been initialized. Leaving out the word `late` might prevent the crash since the string interpolation would then just make it `Bearer null`

Answer (score 1):

Avoid posting screenshots of code, post text instead!

In your constructor, you use `$token` as a variable, but since it's marked `late`, Dart expects you to assign a value to it before you use it. You could either set your main header at a later point (once you retrieved your token), or pass the token into the `ApiClient` instead, to ensure it's defined.

The `$token` string interpolation is resolved when you assign the String, it won't keep token as a variable but instead get its value (which results in the error, but could also be null if token wasn't marked late), and try to put that into the String

#### A solution

You could make a separate constructor which is retrieves the token and sets it that way.

```dart
final String? token;
final String appBaseUrl;

// Add token to the original constructor
ApiClient({required this.appBaseUrl, required this.token}) {
  baseUrl = appBaseUrl;
  timeout = Duration(seconds: 30,);
  _mainHeader = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
  };
}

// Add this new method to create one asynchronously
static Future<ApiClient> withToken({required String appBaseUrl}) async {
  token = await asyncGetToken(); // some function that somehow retrieves the token (and takes some time to do so)
  ApiClient client = new ApiClient(
    appBaseUrl: appBaseUrl, 
    token: token,
  );
  return client;
}
```

Now, you can initialize your API client using a method like:

```dart
ApiClient apiClient = await ApiClient.withToken(appBaseUrl: 'www.example.com');
```

Comment: I call it a constructor, which it technically isn't, but it functions that way